# Drake - Frame visualization attribute error

Tags: drake

Running the example `/examples/kuka_iiwa_arm/kuka_simulation` gives me the following error:

> Blockquote
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/felix/.cache/bazel/_bazel_felix/6a5b9f62883c4665b1f398a636821629/external/drake_visualizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/director/lcmUtils.py", line 117, in handleMessage
>       callback(msg, channel=channel)
>     File "/home/felix/git/drake/bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer.runfiles/drake/tools/workspace/drake_visualizer/plugin/show_frame.py", line 93, in _handle_message
>       frame_channel.handle_message(msg)
>     File "/home/felix/git/drake/bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer.runfiles/drake/tools/workspace/drake_visualizer/plugin/show_frame.py", line 36, in handle_message
>       vis.updateFrame(transform, name, parent=folder, scale=0.1)
>     File "/home/felix/.cache/bazel/_bazel_felix/6a5b9f62883c4665b1f398a636821629/external/drake_visualizer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/director/visualization.py", line 879, in updateFrame
>       obj.copyFrame(frame)
>   AttributeError: 'ContainerItem' object has no attribute 'copyFrame'

Example was started with:
`bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer &`
`./bazel-bin/examples/kuka_iiwa_arm/kuka_simulation`

`bazel-bin/lcmtypes/drake-lcm-spy` shows that the channel `DRAKE_DRAW_FRAMES` is up and messages are being transmitted.

Information about my system:
Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04
gcc: gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-9ubuntu1~18.04.york0) 7.4.0
python: Python 2.7.15+ // This is the default python version
`bazel run @drake//common:print_host_settings`: gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.09ubuntu1~18.04.york0) 7.4.0
cmake: 3.15.4

drake was built from source using bazel 0.29.0

If I run
`bazel-bin/tools/drake_visualizer &`
`./bazel-bin/manipulation/util/geometry_inspector     ./manipulation/models/iiwa_description/sdf/iiwa14_no_collision.sdf`

The Kuka arm is shown in the visualizer and I can use the sliders to control the configuration of the arm.

Edit: My problem is that when I run `/examples/kuka_iiwa_arm/kuka_simulation`, no frames are displayed in the visualizer.

Comment: This is related to the following PR (with the issue mentioned): https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/11134 - will see if it's still reproducible on `master`, as I'm not sure if we pulled in these updates for Director: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/director/pull/621#issuecomment-479307189

Comment: Confirmed that it's still an issue with our current revisions (using commit: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/commit/2f98a9211), because we're on an old commit of drake visualizer; we need to update to incorporate this commit: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/director/commit/85e98c65

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed once we update the version of Director shipped with Drake.
We're already in the process of doing so via our Python 3 update: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12046

Thanks for reporting this!